# Select from table.column1, process the value, insert on column 2 and 3

Tags: php, database, postgresql

2 more columns were recently added to a table with already lots of columns and rows.

These 2 columns (**B** and **C**) must contain similar values that the table had already from another column, **A**.

**table.A**:
**2018-05-15h00:00/2018-05-15h23:00** [text] (value may differ but format is the same)

**table.B** must be:
**2018-05-15 00:00:00** [Timestamp without timezone]

**table.C** must be:
**2018-05-15 23:00:00** [Timestamp without timezone]

It would be quite easy from PHP (please don't mind the code, it's just an example):

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT a FROM table;";
$result = pg_query($conn, $query);
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $var = explode("/", $row[0]);
  $varB = str_replace("h", " ", $var[0]);
  $varB .= ":00";
  $varC = str_replace("h", " ", $var[1]);
  $varC .= ":00";
  $query = pg_query($conn, "UPDATE table SET b='$varB', c='$varC' WHERE a='$row[0]';" );
}
?>
```

But I would rather use a proper method for that. I'm not sure for how long this SQL will run, the idea is to make the job as smooth as possible. If PHP is the best choice here, I'd go for this. Looking for suggestions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use just a MySQL query instead of PHP calls

```
UPDATE Table_B
SET
    Table_B.col1 = Table_A.col1,
    Table_B.col2 = Table_A.col2
FROM
    Tableone AS Table_B
    INNER JOIN TableTwo AS Table_A
        ON Table_B.some_id = Table_A.some_id
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understood the question :/